# dynamically exclude column names in proc sql macro

Tags: sas

I have a proc sql statement in a macro function that selects column names from `dictionary.columns`. I would like to exclude column names based on multiple string patterns that are passed a arguments - see below

```
%symdel keepnames;

%macro test(data=, col=);
    %global keepnames;

    %let data_lib = %sysfunc(upcase(%sysfunc(scan("&data", 1, "."))));
    %let data_data = %sysfunc(upcase(%sysfunc(scan("&data", 2, "."))));
    %put &data_lib;
    %put &data_data;

    proc sql noprint;
        select name into :keepnames separated by " "
        from    dictionary.columns
        where   libname = "&data_lib" and
        memname = "&data_data" and
        upcase(name) not like upcase("&col.");
    quit;
%mend test;

%test(data=sashelp.cars, col=mpg w)
%put &keepnames;
```

Ideally, the `col` argument would turn into `%mpg%, %w%` thereby excluding any column names with mpg or w in their name.

There are a couple issues I'm encountering. First, I can't quite figure out how to hide the `%` from the macro processor. I tried using `%str()` in several ways but without luck. Second, I can't easily add `%` symbols around the words in the `col` argument. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It looks to me like it should work if you call like `%test(data=sashelp.cars, col=%nrstr(%mpg% ))` .  That said, there are some macro design issues that should be addressed.  I'll try to write a real answer in the rare case that someone doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: Based on previous posts, I had tried something like that - at least for me it does not generate the macro variable - `WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference KEEPNAMES not resolved.`

Comment: Make sure you have a space after the final % sign before the closing parentheses.  Suggest you start a new session, and run it with that space.  It works for me .  Another working option is `%test(data=sashelp.cars, col=%nrstr(%mpg%%))`.  But definitely start a fresh session.  You may be trapped in unmatched parentheses.

Comment: Yes, that was an issue for me - what does the extra space accomplish? (Sorry - thought it was a typo)

Comment: Without a space %nrstr(%mpg%)  won't work, because the first ( opens %nrstr, but the closing parenthesis is not seen because %) is the way you hide a parenthesis inside of %ntstr.  If you add a space %nrstr(%mpg% )  works because now the closing parenthesis is not hidden.  That said, it's a hack.  %nrstr(%mpg%%) is better.  And more importantly, you've already got a real answer from Richard, which you wisely accepted. : )

Comment: Great explanation - thank you - I do like the prxmatch option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the macro parameter name to be something better informing, for example

```
%macro fetch_names (data=, dropPattern=, resultVar=fetchedNames)
   ...
%mend;
```

Consider passing a regular expression instead of a space separated list of values that would have to be iterated over.

```
 %let fetchedNames = ;
 %fetch_names (
   data = sashelp.cars
 , dropPattern = mpg|w     /* <------- regular expression pattern */
 , resultVar = fetchedNames
 )
```

The innard of the macro would be similar.

- change
   `into :keepnames` to
   `into :&resultVar`
- change
   `upcase(name) not like upcase("&col.")` to
   `not prxmatch("/&dropPattern./i", name)`

Comment: Thanks! This should be much easier to implement in many different cases.

Comment: Left second arg off (the `name`), oops. Will fix

Comment: Thanks - that did it

Answer (score 0):

I made use of the contains operator in the following and looped through the arguments in col to generate separate tests for each exclusion. For some reason I don't have cars so I used class:

```
%symdel keepnames;

%macro test(data=, col=);
    %global keepnames;

    %let data_lib = %sysfunc(upcase(%sysfunc(scan("&data", 1, "."))));
    %let data_data = %sysfunc(upcase(%sysfunc(scan("&data", 2, "."))));
    %put &data_lib;
    %put &data_data;
    %let i = 1;
    %let exclusion = %scan(&col,&i);

    proc sql noprint;
        select name into :keepnames separated by " "
        from    dictionary.columns
        where   libname = "&data_lib" and
        memname = "&data_data"

        %do %while(&exclusion ne );
            and upcase(name) not contains upcase("&exclusion")

            %let i = %eval(&i + 1);
            %let exclusion = %scan(&col,&i);
        %end;
        ;
    quit;
%mend test;

option mprint;
%test(data=sashelp.class, col=ame x)
%put &keepnames;

%test(data=sashelp.class)
%put &keepnames;

%test(data=sashelp.class, col=e)
%put &keepnames;
```